# Optional parts in javascript regular expression (with capture groups)

Tags: javascript, regex, expression

I have a question regarding how to implement optional parts to a regular expression. I have taken an example from parsing good-old text adventure input. This highlights my task pretty well. Here is an example to show what I'm after:

```
var exp = /^([a-z]+)(?:\s([a-z0-9\s]+)\s(on|with)\s([a-z\s]+))?$/i;

var strings = [
    "look",
    "take key",
    "take the key",
    "put key on table",
    "put the key on the table",
    "open the wooden door with the small rusty key"
];

for (var i=0; i < strings.length;i++) {
    var match = exp.exec(strings[i]);

    if (match) {
        var verb = match[1];
        var directObject = match[2];
        var preposition = match[3];
        var indirectObject = match[4];

        console.log("String: " + strings[i]);
        console.log("  Verb: " + verb);
        console.log("  Direct object: " + directObject);
        console.log("  Preposition: " + preposition);
        console.log("  Indirect object: " + indirectObject);    
    } else {
        console.log("String is not a match: " + strings[i]);
    }
    console.log(match);
}
```

My regular expression works for the first and the three last strings.

I know how to get the correct result using other methods (like .split()). This is an attempt to learn regular expressions so I'm not looking for an alternative way to do this :-)

I have tried adding more optional non-capture groups, but I couldn't get it to work:

```
var exp = /^([a-z]+)(?:\s([a-z0-9\s]+)(?:\s(on|with)\s([a-z\s]+))?)?$/i;
```

This works for the three first string, but not the three last.

So what I want is:
first word, some characters until a specified word (like "on"), some characters until end of string

The tricky part is the different variants.

Can it be done?

WORKING SOLUTION:

```
exp = /^([a-z]+)(?:\s((?:(?!\s(?:on|with)).)*)(?:\s(on|with)\s(.*))?)?$/i;
```

Comment: `?:` just generates a non matching group and has nothing to do with Optional. Optional Groups have an `?` at the end, or are quantified to be clearly optional, like `{0,1}`. However it wouldn't make sence to use that much optional groups, as you then need to check each Match Group for existence.

Comment: I know the ?: represents a non-capture group. I tried to make it optional by using the syntax:  
`(?:this part is optional)?`

Comment: I think the problem is that the first optional group definition is too greedy. It matches the rest of the string, not just until the word "on" or "with"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps some regex like this :

```
var exp = /^([a-z]+)(?:(?:(?!\s(?:on|with))(\s[a-z0-9]+))+(?:\s(?:on|with)(\s[a-z0-9]+)+)?)?$/i;
```

The group `\s[a-z0-9]+` captures a word preceded by a space.

`(?!\s(?:on|with))` avoids this word to be "on" or "with".

Thus `(?:(?!\s(?:on|with))(\s[a-z0-9]+))+` is the list of words before "on" or "with".

You can test [here](http://regexr.com?33149).

Comment: It didn't give me exactly what I wanted, but it is a step in the right direction. The match for "the small rusty key" became "key", and "the wooden table" became "table". But as I said, it is a step in the right direction. I think the ?!-part is the key to getting this to work.

Comment: And what do you want? Perhaps by moving the first `?:` in the first group of words : `^([a-z]+)((?:(?!\s(?:on|with))(?:\s[a-z0-9]+))+(?:\s(?:on|with)(\s[a-z0-9]+)+)?)?$`.

Comment: I´m not sure what the practice is here on Stackoverflow, but this answer steered me in the right direction. My solution was `exp = /^([a-z]+)(?:\s((?:(?!\s(?:on|with)).)*)(?:\s(on|with)\s(.*))?)?$/i;`

Comment: Ok, in fact you have mainly replaced the alphanumeric words `[a-z0-9]+` by any group of characters `(.*)`. Great if that works like that!